# SAPUI5 web application does not work properly

Tags: javascript, eclipse, sapui5

I am trying to make a hello world web full-screen application. So, I created a new project called Hello world. Then, I created a folder called WebContent. Inside it, I put the following code in an index.html as following.

**WebContent/ index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.Project":""}'>
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
        var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idpage1"});
        var page1 = sap.ui.view({id:"idpage1", viewName:"com.Project.HelloWorld.Page1", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
        
        app.addPage(Page1);
        app.placeAt("content");

        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in this directory `WebContent/ HelloWorld` I put a file called Page1.controller.js with the following code in it

**WebContent/ HelloWorld/ Page1.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
   "use strict";        
    return Controller.extend("com.Project.HellowWorld.Page1", {         
    });
});
```

Also, I made another file as following

**WebContent/ HelloWorld/ Page1.view.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>

<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="com.Project.HellowWorld.Page1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Full screen App">
        <content>                 
        </content>           
     </Page>
</core:View>
```

The problem is that the background appears. But, the whole content does not appear on the page as required.

I am following a course published by an external consultant by the way.

Comment: Have you looked in Dev Tools console? Probably some error messages are showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem.

In the `index.html:20` this part of my code is written like this `app.addPage(Page1);` So, I just replaced it with `app.addPage(page1);` and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<page>` is written lowercase. It should be `<Page>`.

You should get the following error in console though:
`Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/page.js' from .../resources/sap/m/page.js: 404 - Not Found`

Comment: you are right! but this problem happened while I was copying and pasting the code to the website. <Page> is written correctly in eclipse.